# Initializing an array with a function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer-list

I'm trying to write a helper function that converts two arrays to an array of pairs, which is used to initialize some static data stored in my program.

So far, I've written a constexpr function that accepts two arrays of the same length, and returns a `std::array` by value, which is then used to initialize an array.

```
inline std::array<param_t, N> transpose(int const (&mg)[N], int const (&eg)[N]) {
    std::array<param_t, N> ret{};
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        ret[i] = {mg[i], eg[i]};
    }
    return ret;
}
```

```
struct some_params {
    param_t mat[5] = transpose({92, 367, 444, 583, 1342}, {88, 370, 394, 646, 1233});
}
```

This generates a compiler error: `Array initializer must be an initializer list`. I'm not sure how I can return a `std::initializer_list`, given that it doesn't have a suitable constructor and is designed as a temporary. For various reasons, I can't change the type of mat to `std::array`.

How can I initialize an array like this from a function?

Comment: Why isn't `mat` an `std::array<param_t, 5>`?

Comment: What you do is a specialized implementation of [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). I really recommend that you use the standard `std::transform` function instead.

Comment: @NathanOliver Elsewhere, there's a reinterpret_cast of all of `some_params` to `int*` and I'm not sure if std::array will mess with alignment by storing length. I also have some arrays with higher dimensions and I'd like to avoid the std::array syntax there if at all possible.

Comment: @konsolas You can treat a `std::array` as an array.  It has a `data` member if you need a pointer.  You don't need to worry about the size being stored in the array objects since it is part of the type, just like it is with raw arrays.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid `std::array<std::array<std::array<std::array<param_t, 2>, 2>, 64>, 2>`?

Comment: @konsolas Not really but if you need to write it multiple times, `using name_of_thing = std::array<std::array<std::array<std::array<param_t, 2>, 2>, 64>;` makes life easier.

Comment: This is a job for [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Comment: Alternatively, there is [`boost::zip_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure how I can return a std::initializer_list,

A non-empty `std::initializer_list` can only be constructed using a [*brace-init-list*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). You cannot build up a `std::initializer_list` from an empty object.

For your specific use case, you may use:

```
std::array<param_t, 5> mat = transpose({92, 367, 444, 583, 1342}, {88, 370, 394, 646, 1233});
```

Comment: `auto` is apparently not allowed in a non-static struct member, but it looks like there isn't any way around this other than by just using std::array.